Why is Plyer vibrate method raising an exception?
I'm coding an app and currently trying to use the vibrate method provided by Plyer.
Here's my Python code:
class SplashScreen(MDScreen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SplashScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.main_app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        self.splash_screen_counter = 0

    def on_enter(self):
        msg = ""

        if vibrator.exists():
            msg = "Device has a vibrator!"
            vibrator.pattern(pattern=(0, 1), repeat=-1)
            vibrator.vibrate(time=2)

        # after 2 seconds, add the label
        Clock.schedule_once( partial(self.add_label_to_splash_screen, msg if msg else "Gettings things ready for you." ) , 2 )

        # increase the counter
        self.splash_screen_counter += 2

And here are the relevant sections of buildozer.spec file
# (list) Application requirements

# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,plyer

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.2.0

#android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)
android.permissions = WAKE_LOCK, VIBRATE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 31

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
android.minapi = 21

When I run the code, I get this error, even though permission is granted in the buildozer.spec file. Where could the problem be?
Here's the error message as text
File "/storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/splash_page_tutorial-7.py", line 83, in on_enter
vibrator.pattern(pattern=(0, 1), repeat=-1)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.11/site-packages/plyer/facades/vibrator.py", line 70, in pattern
self._pattern(pattern=pattern, repeat=repeat)
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.11/site-packages/plyer/platforms/android/vibrator.py", line 41, in _pattern
vibrator.vibrate(
File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 1164, in jnius.jnius.JavaMultipleMethod.call
File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 878, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call
File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 972, in jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_method
File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 79, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Requires VIBRATE permission java.lang.SecurityException

Please post the error message as text, not as screenshot.

@deceze, I've added the eye message as text. Kindly check

To solve it we can use the required permission request for each, the function does not contains errors, it can be the app requiring to get permission at runtime, nevertheless the feature is available since API Level 1, doing some tests implementing the code below and compiling to APK using buildozer, we get:
Python script (application is working):
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
Screen:

    BoxLayout:
        padding: dp(90)
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDLabel:
            id: infos
            text: "Press the button"

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "pencil"
            text: "Test device"
            on_release: app.ask_permission(root.ids.infos),app.ask2(root.ids.infos),app.on_enter2(root.ids.infos)'''


class Examplejbsidis(MDApp):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


    def on_enter2(self,inform):
        try:
            from plyer import vibrator
            msg = ""

            if vibrator.exists():
                msg = "Device has a vibrator!"
                vibrator.pattern(pattern=(0, 1), repeat=-1)
                vibrator.vibrate(time=2)
        
        except Exception as e:
            j=inform.text
            inform.text=str(e) + str(j)

    def ask2(self,inform):
        try:
            from jnius import autoclass
            from android import activity
            activity = activity.current_activity
            Vibrator = autoclass('android.os.Vibrator')
            permission = 'android.permission.VIBRATE' #per Android developer documentation states this is needed
            if not activity.checkSelfPermission(permission):
                # If not, request permission
                if not activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission):
                    activity.requestPermissions([permission], 1)
                else:
                    print("Permission already granted.")
            else:
                print("Permission already granted.")

            # Wait for the result
            

            activity.onActivityResult = self.on_permission_result
        
        except Exception as e:
            j=inform.text
            inform.text=str(e) + str(j)
        
    def on_permission_result(self,requestCode, resultCode, data):
        if requestCode == 1 and resultCode == 0:
            print("Permission denied.")
        elif requestCode == 1 and resultCode == -1:
            print("Permission granted.")
        else:
            print("Unknown result.")
            
    def ask_permission(self,inform):
        try:
            from jnius import autoclass
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            #get permission from user
            request_permissions([Permission.VIBRATE])
        
        except Exception as e:
            j=inform.text
            inform.text=str(e) + str(j)


Examplejbsidis().run()

Android 10 (A10):
No errors at all, permission granted already from Manifest and runtime:
Phone vibrates as expected when pressing the buttons

Android 12 (A31):
An error occurred:
#JVM exception occurred: vibrate: Neither user 10532 nor current process has android.permission.VIBRATE java.lang.SecurityException

This occurred because the buildozer project did not include android.permission.VIBRATE in the manifest, but later it did it:
New error:
module **'android.activity'** has no attribute **'current_activity'**, this error does not exist in Android 10.

Correcting code, now vibrates normally:
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
Screen:

    BoxLayout:
        padding: dp(90)
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDLabel:
            id: infos
            text: "Press the button"

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "pencil"
            text: "Test device" #app.ask2(root.ids.infos)
            on_release: app.ask_permission(root.ids.infos),app.on_enter2(root.ids.infos)'''


class Example(MDApp):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


    def on_enter2(self,inform):
        try:
            from plyer import vibrator
            msg = ""

            if vibrator.exists():
                msg = "Device has a vibrator!"
                vibrator.pattern(pattern=(0, 1), repeat=-1)
                vibrator.vibrate(time=2)
        
        except Exception as e:
            j=inform.text
            inform.text=str(e) + str(j)

    def ask2(self,inform):
        try:
            from jnius import autoclass
            from android import activity
            activity = activity.current_activity
            Vibrator = autoclass('android.os.Vibrator')
            permission = 'android.permission.VIBRATE' #per Android developer documentation states this is needed
            if not activity.checkSelfPermission(permission):
                # If not, request permission
                if not activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission):
                    activity.requestPermissions([permission], 1)
                else:
                    print("Permission already granted.")
            else:
                print("Permission already granted.")

            # Wait for the result
            

            activity.onActivityResult = self.on_permission_result
        
        except Exception as e:
            j=inform.text
            inform.text=str(e) + str(j)
        
    def on_permission_result(self,requestCode, resultCode, data):
        if requestCode == 1 and resultCode == 0:
            print("Permission denied.")
        elif requestCode == 1 and resultCode == -1:
            print("Permission granted.")
        else:
            print("Unknown result.")
            
    def ask_permission(self,inform):
        try:
            from jnius import autoclass
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            #get permission from user
            request_permissions([Permission.VIBRATE])
        
        except Exception as e:
            j=inform.text
            inform.text=str(e) + str(j)


Example().run()

